# JMS consumer not receiving messages

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I just finished a tutorial on JMS, so it's super new to me and I'm trying to understand the basics. I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis if that matters. I created two simple applications, one named `Producer` and the other named `Consumer`. I run `Producer` first then run `Consumer`. The `Consumer` application never terminates and does not print the messages to the console. Weirdly, if I do not manually terminate `Consumer` and run `Producer` a second time, then I see the messages that `Consumer` should have received printed on the console. What's going on here? How do I get `Consumer` to receive and print messages from `Producer`?

Here's `Producer`:

```java
public class Producer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        connection = cf.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession();
        
        Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/myQueue");
        Topic topic = (Topic) initialContext.lookup("topic/myTopic");
        
        MessageProducer queueProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
        MessageProducer topicProducer = session.createProducer(topic);
        
        TextMessage queueMessage = session.createTextMessage("This message is for the queue2");
        TextMessage topicMessage = session.createTextMessage("This message is for the topic2");
    
        queueProducer.send(queueMessage);
        topicProducer.send(topicMessage);
        
        System.out.println("Message to queue sent: "+ queueMessage.getText());
        System.out.println("Message to topic sent: "+ topicMessage.getText());
        
        initialContext.close();
        
    }

}
```

Here's `Consumer`:

```java
public class Consumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        connection = cf.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession();
        
        Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/myQueue");
        Topic topic = (Topic) initialContext.lookup("topic/myTopic");
        
        MessageConsumer queueConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        MessageConsumer topicConsumer1 = session.createConsumer(topic);
        MessageConsumer topicConsumer2 = session.createConsumer(topic);
        
        connection.start();
        
        TextMessage messageReceivedByQueueConsumer = (TextMessage) queueConsumer.receive();
        TextMessage messageReceivedByTopicConsumer1 = (TextMessage) topicConsumer1.receive();
        TextMessage messageReceivedByTopicConsumer2 = (TextMessage) topicConsumer2.receive();
        
        System.out.println("Message received by queue consumer: "+ messageReceivedByQueueConsumer.getText());
        System.out.println("Message received by topic consumer 1: "+ messageReceivedByTopicConsumer1.getText());
        System.out.println("Message received by topic consumer 2: "+ messageReceivedByTopicConsumer2.getText());
        
        connection.close();
        initialContext.close();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example LGTM, see https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/standard/queue . Can you share your `jndi.properties` file?

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks for editing the question. I'm still learning how to use the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're observing is, in fact, the expected behavior.

Since you run the `Producer` application first a message is being sent to a queue and a topic when no consumer/subscriber exists on either. The message sent to the queue is stored in the queue because that's how JMS queues work. The message sent to the topic is discarded since there are no subscriptions to receive the message. Again, this is how JMS topics work.

Then when your `Consumer` application runs the `queueConsumer` receives the message sent to the queue, but since you're invoking `receive()` with no timeout on `topicConsumer1` the application will simply block forever since there are no messages in the topic consumer's subscription. This blocking prevents the message received from the queue from being printed.

You should run your consuming application *first* and then run your producer while the consuming application is still running. Then you should see all the messages received and printed as you assumed they would be.

Comment: This is awesome and super simple to understand! Thank you so much for breaking it down so clearly!